# Certificate Issuer Replace by CN or OU,System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection CSV Error

Tags: regex, powershell, certificate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>Issuer</th>
    <th>...</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection
</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection
</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to replace `$_.Issuer` from my array to include `CN=` only if there is no `OU=`.

So the logic is

1. If there is no CN= at the beginning of the line, get the `OU=` from `$_Issuer` field
2. Else get the text from `CN=` from the `$_.Issuer` field and return it
   `$_.Issuer` field

```bsh
cls

$array = @() 

Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object ({
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PSPath" -Value $_.PSPath
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FriendlyName" -Value $_.FriendlyName
    if ( $_.Issuer -Match ("(?<=^(?:CN|OU)=)[^,\r\n]+")) {
        $matches.Values
    }
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Issuer" -Value $matches.values
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NotAfter" -Value $_.NotAfter
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NotBefore" -Value $_.NotBefore
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SerialNumber" -Value $_.SerialNumber
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Thumbprint" -Value $_.Thumbprint
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DnsNameList" -Value $_.DnsNameList
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Subject" -Value $_.Subject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Version" -Value $_.Version

    $array += $obj

    $obj = $null 
})

$array | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\temp4.csv"
```

For example,

```
CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
CN=Avast Web/Mail Shield Root, O=Avast Web/Mail Shield, OU=generated by Avast Antivirus for SSL/TLS scanning
OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp., OU=Microsoft Time Stamping Service Root, OU=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Trust Network
```

should return

```
Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010
Avast Web/Mail Shield Root
Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp.
```

But now I have a problem that the issuer is not saving to the CSV file after finding the correct match. When it has found a match, Issuer column in my CSV file fills in "System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection". Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Before rolling out any complex solutions, why not try `(?<=^(?:CN|OU)=)[^,\r\n]+`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work https://regex101.com/r/KmgGwS/5

Comment: @123testing123 you need to enable the global and multiline flags on regex101

Comment: Ah thank you! Sorry, it was my first time using that website.Now my problem is trying to add this logic to my array so I could save it to csv file.  So far I have if($_.Issuer -Match "(?<=^(?:CN|OU)=)[^,\r\n]+")

{
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Issuer" -Value $_.Issuer 
} But it doesn't seem to work. My csv file is now missing the "Issuer" column.

Comment: It [**does** seem to work](https://regex101.com/r/KmgGwS/6), you did not use the right modifiers at the regex101 site. Why do you try at regex testing site? Try it in the code you have. Regex101 does not support .NET regex anyway.

Comment: `Matches.values` contains a collection of values which can't be converted by the `Export-Csv` cmdlet. To convert this to a single string, try: `$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Issuer" -Value "$($matches.values)"`

Comment: If I put your "**For Example**" in a here string, it doesn't match the regular expression. Please remove unnecessary information from your question and try to create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So, my regex worked for you. Please consider accepting/upvoting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57562660/3832970).

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need is actually a pattern matching a non-comma chunk after either `OU=` or `CN=` at the start of a string (Powershell process files line by line by default, so it will act like at the start of the line):

```
(?<=^(?:CN|OU)=)[^,]+
```

If you read a whole file in, you will need to force `^` to match the line start position with a `(?m)` `RegexOptions.Multiline` modifier:

```
(?m)(?<=^(?:CN|OU)=)[^,\r\n]+
```

**Details**

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on, enabling `^` to match the start of a line position
- `(?<=^(?:CN|OU)=)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `CN=` or `OU=` at the start of a string immediately to the left of the current position
- `[^,\r\n]+` - one or more chars other than a comma, CR and LF symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Wiktor + iRon, I was able to answer my question. This solves the OU and CN answer and also being able to write to csv file with the matched OU and CN Issuer. This is the complete script that works. :)

```
cls

$array = @() 

Get-ChildItem -recurse |
foreach-object ({ 

$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PSPath" -Value $_.PSPath
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FriendlyName" -Value $_.FriendlyName
if( $_.Issuer -match ("(?<=^(?:CN|OU)=)[^,\r\n]+")) {
$matches.values
}
$Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Issuer" -Value "$($matches.values)"
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NotAfter" -Value $_.NotAfter
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NotBefore" -Value $_.NotBefore
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SerialNumber" -Value $_.SerialNumber
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Thumbprint" -Value $_.Thumbprint
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DnsNameList" -Value $_.DnsNameList
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Subject" -Value $_.Subject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Version" -Value $_.Version

$array += $obj


$obj = $null 
$matches.values = $null

}) 

$array | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\temp4.csv"
```